# How to override ID's in Drupal and comply to CSS Lint|?

Tags: theming

How to override ID's ( or not use ID'S) in Drupal and use Classes only to comply to CSS LINT ( consider that I must use a subtheme and not always can write the HTML. I will have to work with what Drupal gives me). Can anyone advise me about best practices?

Comment: IDs in HTML where invented for a reason, CSS LINT nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subtheme you can override whatever templates contain IDs and change them to use classes instead, updating the CSS along the way.

For example you can override the node template by creating a node.tpl.php file in your subtheme, and the markup can be changed to whatever you need.

You'll have to identify which templates need to be overridden yourself, as there isn't a list available; it will depend on what modules you have installed, and what base theme you're using.

It's also worth bearing in mind that contributed modules (and possibly core modules) may use IDs to target elements in javascript. So test thoroughly, as you might need to make some changes there as well.

*However*

Don't forget that you're just trying to comply with CSS standards here. You don't need to actually remove the IDs to do that, just any CSS that uses them in selectors.

Drupal 8 core conforms to the rule anyway (see .csslintrc in the root), so you should be covered there, but contributed modules may not. That's when you'll need to check manually and maybe override templates/CSS files that they provide.

Earlier versions of Drupal don't conform to the same standards as far as I know so YMMV.

Comment: Hi Clive, Thank you. That confirmed my suspicions and has helped me top plan. You basically have to write everything from scratch. It is a pity there isn't an easier way. I think Drupal is great but why isn't Drupal
using more classes instead of ID's if is meant to be reused?

Comment: It does use plenty of classes, but there's no reason not to use IDs as well - the linter's objection is only to their use in CSS selectors. I updated the answer with a bit more info

Comment: Hi Clive, I am sorry to be so annoying but how to use only CSS in selectors since it is really difficult to override IDs. For instance it takes 256 classes to override one ID: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lzjqh

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean. It takes one class to override one or more IDs. Never 256

Comment: Hi Clive what I am talking about is specificity like Kevin Korte here (https://teamtreehouse.com/community/want-to-know-clearly-about-css-class-id-selectors) mentions "I want to clarify that web browsers do not treat ids and classes the same when they render the page". If you have an ID and a class for the same element the ID will override the class.So my conclusion is in Drupal unless you going to write a lot of code from scratch you will have to accept some IDS contradicting people that are now saying not to use IDS at all.

Comment: Still no idea what you mean, it doesn't take 256 classes to override an id in CSS, regardless of specificity. You just replace the CSS targeting an Id with one targeting a class. It's one-to-one. The things you're talking about aren't related to each other, I think you're getting confused between those two very different things. No one who knows what they're talking about has ever said not to use ids in HTML. Some people will argue that classes are better **for CSS selection**, but that's irrelevant. IDs aren't just for CSS selection, their presence in markup is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: If you subscribe to the opinion (remember that's opinion, not fact) that one shouldn't use IDs in CSS, and you're using code written by someone who disagrees with that opinion, then yeah, you're going to have to make changes to their code. Bit that's true of anything. Drupal makes that easy anyway, you can just exclude CSS files that you don't want, include new ones with standards that match your own, and use the template system to override any relevant markup. But you shouldn't just do that to remove ids, you'll probably break some JS as I mentioned. Just add classes

Comment: Hi Clive, That answered my question and confirmed what I was wondering. Thank you. It is like writing a book and language can be used in many ways. Got it. Estela